# Cannot make an updatable variable in java

Tags: java, oop, variables, methods

So here's my code :

```
public class Shoe {
    String brandName;
    double shoePrice;
    int shoesInStock;

    double totalRevenue;

    public Shoe(String name, double price, int shoesAvailable){
        brandName = name;
        shoePrice = price;
        shoesInStock = shoesAvailable;
    }

    public void shoeSold(){
        totalRevenue = totalRevenue + shoePrice;
        System.out.println("Your new total revenue is " + totalRevenue + "$");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Shoe yeezy = new Shoe("adidas", 75, 10);
        Shoe airforce = new Shoe("nike", 140, 15);

        yeezy.shoeSold();
        airforce.shoeSold();
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Your new total revenue is 75.0$
Your new total revenue is 140.0$
```

Why am I not able to make the totalRevenue variable update and not return to 0 each time, I'm new to java and this was quite an easy task in python I know that java is an oop language but is there no way to make a variable store the value and not return to 0 ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What's zero here? It seems like `totalRevenue` is correct, but you have multiple `Shoe`s. Python is also an OOPL, fwiw. AFAICT `totalRevenue` doesn't belong in a `Shoe` (it could be the total revenue for a *given* shoe), but if you want to add up the total revenue for *all* `Shoe`s there's a missing abstraction.

Comment: The `totalRevenue` is stored in separate _instances_ /objects of the `Shoe` class. While you should truly avoid `static` usage as a beginner, that would be a "hackaround" fix to this situation to make them shared for every instance.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you please further explain how can I fix the problem or what is exactly missing. Thanks!

Comment: @Rogue I just saw all the courses and vids for beginners use the main method as static so I just thought its necessary for the program to run LOL, thanks anyways.

Comment: @GreekDaher it is necessary for the `public static void main`, I meant you could make your variable as `static double totalRevenue;` to share the variable across instances.

Comment: @GreekDaher Tracking total revenue isn't the responsibility of a pair of shoes. `totalRevenue` could be a variable in the `main` method, incremented by the shoe price of each shoe "sold". IRL it's more likely there'd be some form of ledger/POS/etc class that'd track sales/returns/etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly fix the issue, you can just mark `totalRevenue` as `static`.
Although your code lacks many basic coding practices that you need to learn and improve your code.

working code:

```
public class Shoe {
    String brandName;
    double shoePrice;
    int shoesInStock;

    static double totalRevenue;

    public Shoe(String name, double price, int shoesAvailable){
        brandName = name;
        shoePrice = price;
        shoesInStock = shoesAvailable;
    }

    public void shoeSold(){
        totalRevenue = totalRevenue + shoePrice;
        System.out.println("Your new total revenue is " + totalRevenue + "$");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Shoe yeezy = new Shoe("adidas", 75, 10);
        Shoe airforce = new Shoe("nike", 140, 15);

        yeezy.shoeSold();
        airforce.shoeSold();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for everyone's I will try and improve my code as much as I can in the future.